# MCP2515 CAN Transceiver Breadboard vs direct PCB Female Header connection

Tags: stm32, spi, microchip, breadboard, jumper

I have experienced a case, where I connect the MCP2515 over jumper wires to uC and everything works as intended.
However, when I plug MCP2515 directly in the PCB (through female headers), the MCP2515 enters listen-only mode.

Please see my problem description below:

[image]

MCP2515 module link [is here](https://www.az-delivery.de/en/products/mcp2515-can-bus-modul)

As further information:

- no additional elements are connected on breadboard (except Logic Analyzer)
- yes I have tried to move the jumper connections to other parts of breadboard and the outcome is the same

This is totally weird to me. I would have expected the opposite behavior. Has anyone experienced such a case? Perhaps not specifically with MCP2515, but in a similar setup?

Full overview (to get additional idea):

[image]

Comment: It appears you are missing the bus transceiver and termination resistors.

Comment: @Gil Thank you for the comment. I dont see how the lack of terminating resistors or bus transceiver would lead to this problem. If I wouldnt have a proper setup, it should not work in any case. 
However, it is properly terminated and the MCP2515 is part of a module. See updated post :)

Comment: The MCP2515 doesn't have CANH and CANL pins, it has TXCAN and RXCAN pins.  The bus transceiver converts between these signals.  It performs the function of creating the dominant and recessive signals and allows the transmitter to listen for an ACK bit and allows the receiver to send an ACK bit.

Comment: @electrogas The MCP2515 module pcb has transceiver chip (typically cheap clone of TJA1050), converting mcp's tx/rx to external canh/canl.

Comment: Do you have a ground wire along CAN wires? The TJA1050 transceiver is not the one that works without common reference point, and the CAN bus is quasi differential with respect to common ground. Also don't try 1Mbit/s rates with modules that have 8MHz crystal, those lose signal edges or events very frequently.

Comment: @vlad thanks for both hints! I will keep an eye on 1mbit/s. About the common GND, both microcontrollers and CAN transceivers are supplied by the same power supply, referenced to the same ground.

Comment: @electrogas as vlad pointed it out, the module contains CAN controller and CAN transceiver. I was not clear enough :P